# How would I filter by string when returning list items from sharepoint list?

Tags: javascript, filter, sharepoint-online, spfx

I've created a filter text field which successfully filters a list on a webpart. It only accepts a number at the moment and I want it to be able to filter by text. The column in SharePoint is called PPName.
I understand how to implement the JavaScript to filter, but in this case it needs applying to an `sp.web.lists.getByTitle().items.filter().get()` and I can't figure it out.

Here's the filter function on the text field:

As you can see I've filtered and returned results using `let _item2` and this does actually filter correctly on what I'm typing into the field, but it won't filter it by letter and only filters by exact match. I can't think of how to use this filtered `_item2` in the `sp.web.lists...` below it.

```
private _filter = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
 
        this.setState({
          filterValue: newValue,
       
        }, () => {
          const sid = this.state.filterValue;
          let _item = this.state.Items.filter((item) => {return item.Id == sid; });
          let _item2 = this.state.Items.filter((item) => {return item.PPName == sid; });
          
           if (_item && _item.length > 0) {
             sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.filter("Id eq '" + sid + "'").get()
             .then((items: any[]) => {
               let returnedItems: IEIAItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new EIAItem(item); });
               console.log(returnedItems, 'returnedItems, for ID');
               this.setState({
                 ItemsForPages: returnedItems
        
               });
             });
            
           } else if(_item && _item.length === 0){
             this._getListItems();
             var AllItems = this.state.Items;
             this.setState({
               ItemsForPages: AllItems,
               isFiltered: 'false'
              
             });
            
          }
          if (_item2 && _item2.length > 0) {
    
         sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.filter("PPName eq '" + sid + "'").get()
            .then((items: any[]) => {
           
              let returnedItems: IEIAItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new EIAItem(item); });
           
              this.setState({
                ItemsForPages: returnedItems
        
              });
            });
            
          } else if(_item && _item.length === 0){
            this._getListItems();
            var AllItems2 = this.state.Items;
            this.setState({
              ItemsForPages: AllItems2,
              isFiltered: 'false'
              
            });
            
          }
        });
         
    }   `
```

Any help appreciated naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .filter(`substringof('SUBSTRING',NAMEOFTHEFIELD)`).

In .filter('HERE') you can put any of expressions described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/hh169248(v=nav.90)

If you want use multiple filters (this example with OR):
.filter("substringof('" + searchString + "',Title) or substringof('" + searchString + "',ColumnName)")

Be aware with OR in filters - with large list you can exceed threshold limit (https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/677).

Comment: Hi - where to use that? Before the .filter("PPName eq...?

Comment: Hello, I have just tested it on my environment and made change to the original answer. To be clear (sorry for not to be clear in answer for the 1st time). My whole call looks like this: await sp.web.lists.getById(this.props.ListId).items.filter(`substringof('Heads',Title)`).get();

Comment: I'm getting substringof is not defined when I type in a matched word.

Comment: could you please paste your call code (or use codepen)? everything inside .filter must be string .filter(\`string expression\`)

Comment: //@ts-ignore
         sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.filter(`substringof('sid)`).get()
            .then((items: any[]) => {
              console.log(items, 'items from sp.web');
              let returnedItems: IEIAItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new EIAItem(item); });
           
              this.setState({
                ItemsForPages: returnedItems
        
              });
            });

Comment: I'm halfway to writing the substringof, I'm using an ` (backtick?) as demonstrated in your answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that you are missing name of the column in substringof expression -> .filter(substringof('sid)) => .filter(\`substringof('sid',NAMEOFTHECOLUMN)\`)

Comment: should there be quote marks/back ticks/apostrophes around substringof? e.g: .filter("substringof('si ???

Comment: \` backtick is just for easier string build :-) you can use anything ", ', to build that expression but it must end as valid string expression for filter. In that call .filter('string') it is translated to rest api call like filter= ....

Comment: yes the searchsubstring should be surrounded by ' or ", the name of search column no

Comment: Do I need one before the substringof ?

Comment: yes just like this: .filter("substringof('Heads',Title)") -> i am searching for Heads substring in Title column - my result is item with title "Note from Heads Research"

Comment: I'm saving the entered text into state and then saving that to a var. How do I replace your 'Heads' :) with that variable?

Comment: Just like this: const MyVariable: string = 'Heads'; ->  .filter("substringof('" + MyVariable + "',Title)")

Comment: Nice one. Works as you say. It's getting the apostrophes etc. in the right place. Further question: is it because it's using sp/pnp it has to use such filter methods? Or could I use indexOf or search?
Also, would there be a way to filter it by letter, so if I type in half the search term it would find that?

Comment: pnp/js is "just" making the rest api call easier :-) in the end when you see traffic it is normal rest api call with parameters. You can use any of supported filtering expressions described in documentation (in the answer abowe). PnP/JS will translate it to the rest api call. To make it filter by letter i would suggest to use different approach -> load as much as possible items and filter it on client. It will work with this approach but you would be firing rest calls after any letter ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier and better solution:

```
 var textToSearch = sid;
          let _item3 = this.state.Items.filter((item) => {return item.PPName.toLowerCase().indexOf(textToSearch) >= 0;});
           console.log(_item3, 'item3');
           
          if (_item3 && _item3.length > 0) {
            
            this.setState({
              ItemsForPages: _item3
      
            });
```

Comment: Agree, this is easier solution but it requires to load every item from the list and after that you can filter it . The solution depends on use case. Either you can filter "on client" or "on server". Props and cons are for both solutions.